# How to interupt a Jupyter notebook from the command line

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, ipython

I accidentally told my Jupyter notebook to display 7000 rows of pandas DataFrame all at once (with the max rows variable set to None). As such the web interface is completely unresponsive so I can't interrupt it normally. I don't want to have to rerun all of the previous cells in the notebook to get back to my previous position.

Is there a way to interrupt the kernel from the command line without losing the existing state?

Answer (score -1):

> this can be executed in the command line of the jupyter notebook this may help your question

```
jupyter notebook --help
```